Why does a call to a pointer to member function handle virtual functions even if the class has no virtual methods?
https://godbolt.org/z/W8b3TG5f6
struct A {
    int __attribute__((noinline)) call(int a) {
        return (this->*mfuncP)(a);
    }

    int __attribute__((noinline)) returnArg(int a) {
        return a;
    }

    int (A::*mfuncP)(int) = &A::returnArg;
};

int test(int a) {
    return A().call(a);
}

yields
A::returnArg(int):
        mov     eax, esi
        ret
A::call(int):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        test    al, 1
        je      .L4
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx-1+rax]
.L4:
        jmp     rax
test(int):
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     esi, edi
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], OFFSET FLAT:A::returnArg(int)
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], 0
        call    A::call(int)
        add     rsp, 24
        ret

If I understand correctly, the assembly, in this case, is such that if the function address has the LSB set to 1, it is interpreted as referring to a virtual method (https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-function-pointers) hence the need for the branch. However, class A has no virtual functions, so it is unclear why this handling is done.

It must consider the possibility that the call is virtual, because it isn't actually required that a member pointer of type int (A::*)(int) refers to a member of class A. The only restriction that applies is that it must point to a direct member of either A, a (direct or indirect, non-virtual and unambiguous) base class of A or a class derived (directly or indirectly, non-virtual and unambiguously) from A. And when .* or ->* is used to bind the member function pointer to an object, (only) its most-derived object must contain (directly or indirectly) the member that is referred to. (And the class directly containing the member should not be ambiguous in the most-derived object, see open CWG 2593.)
For example, the following has defined behavior and test must produce 42, for which the call mechanism must consider indirect virtual calls:
struct B : A {
    virtual int vfunc(int) { return 0; };
};

struct C : B {
    int vfunc(int) override { return 42; }
};

int test(int a) {
    C c;
    c.mfuncP = static_cast<int (A::*)(int)>(&B::vfunc);
    return c.call(a);
}


As noted in the comments, if you mark the A as final, then the compiler can infer that mfuncP can not refer to a virtual member function.
GCC performs that optimization, but for some reason still adds the this pointer offset, which is guaranteed to be zero in the call, because A does not have any base classes either.
Clang does not seem to perform that optimization at all at the moment.

However, when using these kind of casts, keep in mind that, while the standard defines the behavior, MSVC's ABI uses a representation for pointer-to-members that is known to not support this. It will produce a warning and miscompile the code. I think there are flags to make it behave standard-conforming (but also probably break ABI).

Compare with the situation where you declare A final  and you promise there will be no derived classes. https://godbolt.org/z/dhq76Mo9P

@PepijnKramer That code generated by GCC also doesn't look optimal to me. The add rdx, rdi is not necessary, since there are no base classes either. In fact, given that all possible members are known and only one could be referred to by the member pointer, the compiler could compile it to a simple jump to returnArg. And Clang doesn't perform this final optimization at all.

"direct member of either A, a base class of A or a class derived from A" Um, no. It doesn't work this way.

@n.m.couldbeanAI With the implicit conversions and static_casts that are permitted, this is the effective result. (It is not possible in all cases though, e.g. when the base is ambiguous.)

With static_cast it may point literally to anything.

@n.m.couldbeanAI The static_cast is either ill-formed or has undefined behavior if the restrictions I mentioned (plus accessibility) are not satisfied. If they are satisfied, then the behavior is well-defined.

Could someone explain why A::call doesn't just boil down to a jump to returnArg in https://godbolt.org/z/dhq76Mo9P? It seems like the additional instructions (e.g. mov/add) are no-ops (just adding 0?). Perhaps this follows a convention I am unaware of?

@CppBeginner As I mentioned in edits to the answer, this seems to just be a (partially) missed optimization by GCC. Somewhere there is logic in GCC that figured out that the call can't be virtual with final on the class, but there was no logic to figure out that without base classes the offset in the member pointer is always 0.

@CppBeginner And then another missed optimization is to figure out that there are only two valid targets with final: returnArg and call itself. If the compiler was then able to determine that call doesn't do anything but perform the member function call, it could replace the call with a jmp to returnArg. But this seems like a very specific situation that I wouldn't expect the compiler to have extra optimization checks for.

@user17732522 Thank you for all the help! Is the offset that you're referring to the offset of the member pointer in the struct? If so, why would this offset be needed at all? Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but I thought the member pointer is already stored in [rsp].
The behavior does not seem to change if I add a non-empty base class: https://godbolt.org/z/axvz6hnEo.

@CppBeginner It is the offset for this, i.e. adj, the second member of the member pointer representation in the Itanium ABI. See https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-function-pointers.

Yes tou are right, I didn´t know this kind of cast can have UB by itself.
